# How to get the fingerprint name that was verfied via fingerprint API

Tags: android

I am working on an Application that will Login via fingerprint but what I want is to get the fingerprint name of that registered fingerprint, I have been searching but I cannot seem to find some answer. Here is my code:

```
  public class FingerprintHandler extends 
   FingerprintManager.AuthenticationCallback {
    private CancellationSignal cancellationSignal;
    private Context appContext;

    public FingerprintHandler(Context context) {
      appContext = context;
  }

public void startAuth(FingerprintManager manager,
                      FingerprintManager.CryptoObject cryptoObject) {

    cancellationSignal = new CancellationSignal();

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(appContext,
            Manifest.permission.USE_FINGERPRINT) !=
            PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    manager.authenticate(cryptoObject, cancellationSignal, 0, this, null);

}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationError(int errMsgId,
                                  CharSequence errString) {
    scannerDialog(errString.toString());
}

public void scannerDialog(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(appContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationHelp(int helpMsgId,
                                 CharSequence helpString) {
    scannerDialog("" + helpString);
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationFailed() {
    scannerDialog("Access denied");
}

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(
        FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result) {
    Log.e("LoginSuccess","Success");
    //After it was verified, I want to get the Fingerprint name of the verified fingerprint


}
}
```

Can anyone please help. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure, but for Android it's hidden because of security reason.

Comment: Okay, how about getting the number of fingerprint registered on the device? Is there a way?

Comment: `FingerprintManager` has a hidden [`getEnrolledFingerprints` method](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/fingerprint/FingerprintManager.java#708). Note that this still doesn't give you access to the actual fingerprint data, but you might be able to find out how many enrolled fingerprints there are. But since it's marked as hidden there's obviously the risk that it could be removed without warning and/or that it won't work on some devices.